# How to keep connection strings and API keys secure in PRODUCTION

Tags: connection-string, api-key

I am about to deploy a .net core application to production ( core 2.2 ). I am aware of user secrets and environment variables to store when still in development. But what are best practices to ENSURE that these passwords and API keys are not exposed in production? And, how safe is it to store these in the appsettings.json on a hosted web server? My app is semi mission critical and it would be a disaster if they leaked out. And lastly are there any open source / paid for code snippets to assist in encrypting these?
Thanks Luke.

Comment: Basically in dotnet it is called secrets (in Docker also). Check the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to store them in the appsettings.json, you may want to consider storing in a Vault if possible (best of these options) or in an environment variable, the registry, or in a file on disk.

Wherever you store it, the sensitive data should not be stored in plaintext, it should always be encrypted. With NET Core you can use Data Protection API (built in so it's free) to encrypt it, or aspnet_regiis.exe. Both of those need to be encrypted and decrypted on the same machine to work.